# About Serial ports in linux

Tags: python, linux

I am writing some code for xbee devices (RF module).

In Windows I connect app to com port writing `COM10`-`COM255` but in linux its like `/dev/ttyUSB0` ....

I would like to know that is it goes like windows in linux to 255. Or exactly how many serial port does Linux support?

Comment: Different serial port types use different drivers, which have their own limits and their own TTY device naming convention. A lot of USB serial device drivers make use of the "usbserial" module to create the TTY device and "usbserial" has a limit of 512 devices named `/dev/ttyUSB0` to `/dev/ttyUSB511`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to install cutecom (it is in apt repository in Debian). It is a very light hyperterminal and the "Device" button show you all COM on your computer.

Another method is to install Arduino development interface. If you know it you can open a COM terminal in the option (or with ctrl+maj+m if I remember).

Hope it will help!